# Multiple layouts in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, layout

Is it possible to have more than one layout for a WPF window?

That is, say I have an application which can be run on a tablet or on a more traditional desktop or laptop.  The table could have a much higher screen resolution than the laptop or desktop, but, because of the smaller physical screen size, it may be better to lay out the controls differently on the tablet.

If this is possible, how do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways, each may have a different advantage based on what you need.

- Attached property that has a different default value, conditionally compiled, with item styles/templates that look for that property
- value converter that takes the platform into account for its output
- multiple XAMLs loaded in code
- completely different platform pages that reuse the controls inside across platforms
- implement the equivalent of Xamarin's [OnIdiom](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=T%3AXamarin.Forms.OnIdiom%601), which is probably the best way. I've supplemented my own implementation with an OnIdiomExtension: IMarkupExtension so I can use it inside attributes without having to break them out as separate elements

I'm sure the list can go on, there's always 10 ways to do the same thing in WPF - 9 wrong, 1 right and 1 undocumented that's usually best :)

---

edit: OnIdiom details

Essentially OnIdiom a generic construct that picks one of 3 elements - OnTablet, OnPhone and OnDesktop - each of its generic type. You can also opt out for a non-generic version that just uses UIElement for its elements

Here are a couple examples how it's used in XAML

```
<RowDefinition.Height>
  <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="GridLength" Phone="1.25*" Tablet="1.35*" />
</RowDefinition.Height>


<OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="View">
  <OnIdiom.Phone>
    <local:BuildingAreasView/> 
  </OnIdiom.Phone>
  <OnIdiom.Tablet> 
    <Grid x:Name="gridRoot">....</Grid>
  </OnIdiom.Tablet> 
</OnIdiom>
```

and the markup extension used in XAML:

Here's some sample code from OnIdiomExtension.cs, obviously missing the Tablet and Desktop properties for brevity

```
[ContentProperty ("Default")]
public class OnIdiomExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
    public object Default { get; set; }

    public object Phone { get; set; } 

    public object ProvideValue (IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        object val = Default;

        switch (Device.Idiom) {
        case TargetIdiom.Phone:
            val = Phone ?? Default;
            break;
        }

        return val;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never seen the Xamarin stuff before, as I don't do iOS programing.  Do you have any links to examples of its use? That documentation doesn't really say much of anything to explain how its used.

Comment: see update, you should be able to implement the code behind OnIdiom

Comment: OK, I see how it works, though I do have one question. In the `IMarkUpExtension` implementation you gave, where does the 'Device` object come from?

Comment: Oh, that one is Xamarin, you can achieve the same thing with conditional compilation or make your own Device class that detects the environment run-time